# Low Values - haven't got a clue in PHP

Tags: php, hex

I'm supposed to produce a string 15 characters of Low Values but don't have a clue what they are or how to produce them.

I've seen a file which has a string of 15 characters of Low Values followed by an 8 characters of date and it simply looked like 15 spaces.

I'm working in PHP and am guessing it's something to do with hex and started with something like this but it doesn't seem right:

```
for($ii=0; $ii<15; $ii++) 
{
     $strLowValues .= chr(dechex(0000));

        //or
        //$strLowValues .= chr(0);


}


print($strLowValues.date(Ymd));
```

Am basically, completely lost, and any help would be apprecaited!

Thanks

Comment: Well, the sensible thing to do would be to ask the person who told you to do it. If you don't know *what it is you are trying to do*, I don't see how we can help you do it.

Comment: I think you need to define what "low value" means. It sounds like you want to left-pad a date, but your question is nearly indecipherable, your terminology is non-standard, and your desired result is a mystery..

Comment: turns out my code was correct; but thanks for at least looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "Low Values" has no inherent meaning in PHP.

Ask your professor what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Your code makes absolutely no sense. `$strLowValues` is a string, which you're filling with nulls. You then try to treat it an object(?) to convert that null-filled string into a date string?

What is this code supposed to do?

I suggest you learn basic PHP syntax first.

Comment: It's not being treated as an object; I think you're confusing concatanating the $strLowValues and the date - but thanks for trying.